# overlay a div over images jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm trying to display a div by clicking on an image. the div will contains an image or a video.
I will have several images to click on with content attached.
with my actual JS, all div are displayed when cliking on the image.
I use Custom Fields to enter my images and iframe so my code need to be dynamic.
I don't know how to fix it.
Also in my actual code the div disapear when clicking outside of it, I would like to add a text link over to close it when clicking on it.

here is mu JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mix").click(function(){
    $(".photos_overlay").toggle();
  });
});
```

My Html :

```
<div class="mix photos" data-myorder="20140307">
<img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_11.jpg" class="photo_medias">
</div>
<div class="photos_overlay" data-myorder="20140307">
<img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_11.jpg" class="photo_medias_overlay">
</div>
<br>
<div class="mix videos" data-myorder="20140319">
<img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_21.jpg" class="photo_medias">
</div>
<div class="photos_overlay" data-myorder="20140307">
<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and my CSS :

```
.photo_medias{width:233px;height:133px}
.container .mix.photos{width:233px;height:133px}
.container .mix.videos{width:233px;height:133px}
.photos_overlay{width:967px;height:384px;background-color:black;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:none}
.photo_medias_overlay{width:706px;height:364px}
```

here is JSfidlle to see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/aaWLJ/12/

can anybody help me with this ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Are your talking about this? `$(this).next(".photos_overlay").toggle();` in your `click` event

Comment: I have added my answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a little: 
**HTML**

```
<br />
<div class="mix photos" data-myorder="20140307">
    <div class='closeFrame' style="display: none; position:absolute;top:0;">CloseMe</div>
    <img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_11.jpg" class="photo_medias">
</div>

<div class="photos_overlay" data-myorder="20140307">
    <img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_11.jpg" class="photo_medias_overlay">
</div>
<br>
<div class="mix videos" data-myorder="20140319">
    <div class='closeFrame' style="display: none; position:absolute;top:0;">CloseMe</div>
    <img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/media_21.jpg" class="photo_medias">
</div>
<div class="photos_overlay" data-myorder="20140307">
    <iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

As you can see I have added a parent `div` elements for both overlays and a `div` CloseMe
Also I have changed some CSS (You can change it to what ever you want, I just want to show you the main idea how to resolve your issue):

```
.photos_overlay{
    width:967px;
    height:384px;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px; /* I have changed top position just to show the div 'CloseMe'*/
    left:0;
    display:none
}
```

And the **JavaScript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mix").click(function(){
    ShowHide($(this));
  });
  $(".closeFrame").click(function(){
    ShowHide($(this));
  });

  function ShowHide(elem){
    var $mix = $(elem);
    $mix.children(".closeFrame").toggle();
    $mix.next(".photos_overlay").toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Pavlo, it works on the jsfiddle for sure, but as I'm using a jquery to display my "mix" div class, I can't not add an extra div before the div class=mix photos or div class=mix videos... is there a way of doing it without adding the extra div ? thanks again for your help

Comment: @mmdwc Why can't you add an extra divs?

Comment: because i'm using MixItUp, to display my content. All my images should be in a <div class="mix">, and I'm also switching between grid and list view, a lot of parameters... is it possible to continue this conversation by tchat ?

Comment: @mmdwc Unfortunately I must leave. Just tell me what about another divs like `CloseMe` are you able to add them or not? If not, so how do you want to close your overlay?

Comment: yes I can add a CloseMe div no problem, but it has to be inside my <div class="mix photos"> or <div class="mix video">, or outside my main container div, do you see what I mean ?

Comment: if you have a few minutes left, in my previsous code when clicking on the image to open the overlay I had those 2 functions :
$('.scroll_bloc_1_medias').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top");
$('.scroll_bloc_1_medias').mCustomScrollbar("disable");

and when closing the photo this one : 
$('.scroll_bloc_1_medias').mCustomScrollbar("update");

now that the code has changed I don't know how to add this, can you help ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what is mCustomScrollbar. You should better add a new question

Comment: In fact it's just a simple function, like a .css or .addClass... just when clicking on the .mix I want two functions to execute, and when clickin on closeFrame another one, it has nothing to do with mCustomScrollbar

Comment: As i understand, you just need to add first 2 func. Inside .mix event click after ShowHide func. and the last one func. Inside .CloseFrame event click after ShowHide func. Sorry, have to go